# How can I create a video from an audio file and an image file(s)?

Tags: applications, audio, video, images

I have an audio file, and an image file (or several image files). How can I create a video that combine the audio and image files? For example, the audio file is a recording of reading a script, and the image file(s) is screenshot(s) of the script.

Comment: This sounds like what a video editing program does. Just be aware of our sister site: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour You may want to mention where the images are as Google Photos might be able to do what you want: https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6128862?sjid=11010401790314884675-NA

Comment: I may want to mention that I can't access Google services until someone helps me climb over GFW.